# How to enable github actions access gradle properties?

Tags: android, gradle, github, build.gradle, github-actions

My android project uses some keys in gradle properties `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. This is intentionally ignored by git. Is there a way to let github actions access these properties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties), there are three places one can have a `gradle.properties` file, and one of them includes the project's root folder.

If you needed `gradle.properties` in github actions, then create one in the root folder of your project and commit to git. The one in your home directory should remain there.

---

If it is really your desire not to commit any gradle.properties file to git, my first question would be Why?

Here is another way to do it using [secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets).

Assuming you called the secret `GRADLE_PROPERTIES`, then you can do something like this in one of your steps:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Restore gradle.properties
    env:
      GRADLE_PROPERTIES: ${{ secrets.GRADLE_PROPERTIES }}
    shell: bash
    run: |
      mkdir -p ~/.gradle/
      echo "::set-env name=GRADLE_USER_HOME::$HOME/.gradle"
      echo ${GRADLE_PROPERTIES} > ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

After this step runs, gradle will now use that file to configure itself, and so will your project.

Answer (score 10):

### 2021 solution

We need to use `$GITHUB_ENV` [environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) to store `GRADLE_USER_HOME`  because the old `::set-env` is [depecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/).

Here is one sample workflow:

```
name: build
on: [ push ]
jobs:
  build-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Restore gradle.properties
        env:
          GRADLE_PROPERTIES: ${{ secrets.GRADLE_PROPERTIES }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.gradle/
          echo "GRADLE_USER_HOME=${HOME}/.gradle" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "${GRADLE_PROPERTIES}" > ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
      - name: Build the app
        run: ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 1):

The  `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` is user-specific properties and should stay out of versioning.

If you have keys or any sensitive data you want to share with your Github Actions consider using Encrypted Secrets.

https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Comment: It is out of versioning but needed to build the project. Are there no similar ways for gradle properties?

Comment: Multiple gradle properties files are merged for a build. You can put properties that are necessary for your CI inside the project gradle properties and version it (`gradle.properties` in project root directory) but not the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html for more details about properties files merging.

Comment: Dont want to commit these to the repository and hence did not put them at project level gradle properties.

Comment: Well in this case try writing the properties with an action that runs a shell script like `echo "your.gradle.property=value" >> gradle.properties`

Comment: For some reason there is no **~/.gradle/gradle.properties** file on my Macbook.